# Access JSON info from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have this api request:

```
module.exports = {
    getResult: function (topic) {
        return axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Lord+of+the+rings&callback=handleResponse')
            .then(function (results) {
                return results.data;
            })
    }
}
```

I can not access the array inside as I have this handleResponse in the API JSON data

Comment: please show the code where you are calling `getResult`

Comment: your response is not correct format. you need to send it as json format

Comment: Can you console.log out results and show us, could you also check the browser console for any errors?

Comment: What do you get as `results.data`? An array? a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this url https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Lord+of+the+rings . Drop the `&callback=handleResponse`

or if you want the keep the existing url you need to add a global handleResponse function something like

```
   <script>
      function handleResponse(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i];
        // in production code, item.text should have the HTML entities escaped.
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.volumeInfo.title;
      }
    }
    </script>
```

But https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Lord+of+the+rings suits your usecase